# ECharts : How to set maximum zoom level in percentage?

Tags: echarts

I want to restrict user to do maximum zoom to 80% for line chart in echarts. Is there any way to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You have at least two ways:

1. The easiest and comfortable:

Add to config component [`DataZoom`](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom), setup it as you needed and [hide](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.show). The component won't show up but will work. And for the last step just dispatch the action `dataZoom`:

```
chartInstance.dispatchAction({
    type: 'dataZoom',
    dataZoomIndex: 0,

    // set as percents
    start: '20%',
    end: '80%',

    // or set as values
    startValue: 1234,
    endValue: 4321
})
```

2. Difficult way:

The each Axes in Echarts has [two attributes](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.min): `min` and `max` that can control view window of axis. Just change it as you need. Also you can pass callback to attributes that will change the value when Echarts draw chart.

Comment: Update: Echarts 5 requires start and end to Numbers